# How to set Default name in textbox in asp.net mvc3 razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my project login Form i have to implement Default Display and when we click on the textbox ,textbox has to be in blank and vice - versa.This is my code

```
<li><i class="icon-user"></i>@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.UserName, new { @class = "login-user-input", autocomplete = "off", @value="UserName"})</li>

                            <li><i class="icon-key"></i> @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Password, new { @class = "login-user-input", autocomplete = "off" })</li>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `placeholder` attribute

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.UserName,
    new { 
        @class = "login-user-input", 
        autocomplete = "off", 
        placeholder="UserName"
    })
```